# Стоит ли изобретать велосипед? (разработка собственной OCR)

Tags: распознавание, распознавание-символов, c++

Привет всем! Я разрабатываю специальную систему распознавания рукописного ввода. На данный момент у меня стоит задача написать программный блок, который лишь принимает бинаризованное изображение одной буквы и возвращает значение буквы в цифровом формате (UTF, ASCII, не важно). И вот у меня мысль: быть может, не стоит писать то, что уже давно есть, а использовать готовое? Выбор пал на `Taserract OCR`, по которой у меня есть несколько вопросов:

1. Умеет ли система считывать одиночные символы?
2. Если да, то обработка одного символа должна занять небольшое время, но вот как дело обстоит с обработкой большого количества символов (1-2 тысячи за "сессию")? Быть может, собственная система, приспособленная под чтение одиночных символов, будет работать в разы быстрее, и тогда стоит писать собственную систему?
3. Работа будет вестись с рукописным (но не прописным) текстом. То есть буквы раздельные. Хорошо ли данная система распознает с рукописные данные?
4. Можно ли обучить систему собственным вариантам букв? Можно ли это сделать с помощью импорта в систему готовых бинаризованных GIF-изображений букв?

**Обновление**

Дополню. Распознавать нужно не слитный текст, а "печатный" от руки. И по первому вопросу: одиночные, значит, что на вход программы подается одно небольшое изображение с одной буквой.

Comment: @qwoort, советов на будущее два. Во первых, правильно называйте вопрос, у вас тут больше вопросов по определенному продукту. Во вторых, потратьте некоторое время и опробуйте продукт, это самый лучший вариант, это принесет вам и опыт и понимание, что вам это продукт подходит или нет.